# sbt-web asset output directory setup

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra, xsbt-web-plugin, sbt-web

**Scenario**

I have a fairly simple Scalatra project with Scala.js and LESS for which I need to create an sbt build configuration. The project is separated into three parts: jvm, js, shared code.

My current build config uses xsbt-web-plugin for WAR packaging and I'd like to set up sbt-web so it could deal with the processing of LESS sources.

**The Issue**

With current config, when I run package command, sbt-web puts the assets in *WEB-INF/classes/main/META-INF/resources/webjars/dataretrieverjvm/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT*. I'd like to place them in *WEB_INF/public* instead, but I can't figure out how I could achieve that.

This is how my Build.scala looks like at the moment:

```
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject
import sbt._
import com.earldouglas.xwp._
import play.twirl.sbt._
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.web._
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.less.SbtLess.autoImport._

object DataRetrieverBuild extends Build {
  private val organization       = "Foobar Ltd"
  private val scalaVersion       = "2.11.7"
  private val scalaBinaryVersion = "2.11"
  private val scalatraVersion    = "2.3.1"
  private val akkaVersion        = "latest.release"
  private val scalacOptions      = Seq(
    "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Yinline-warnings", "-optimise", "-target:jvm-1.8", "-Xlint", "-feature"
  )
  private val javacOptions       = Seq(
    "-Xlint:all"
  )
  private val jvmLibraryDependencies    = Def.setting(
    Seq(
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "latest.release",
      "com.mchange" % "c3p0" % "latest.release",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "latest.release",
      "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided",
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "latest.release",
      "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "latest.release",
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % scalatraVersion,
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-auth" % scalatraVersion,
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "latest.release",
      "com.ibm.tools.target" % "was-liberty" % "8.5.x.3" % "provided"
    )
  )
  private val jsLibraryDependencies     = Def.setting(
    Seq(
      "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "latest.release",
      "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "latest.release",
      "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.5" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery")
    )
  )
  private val jsWebjarDependencies      = Def.setting(
    Seq(
      "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "jquery.js" minified "jquery.min.js",
      "org.webjars" % "underscorejs" % "1.8.3" / "underscore.js" minified "underscore-min.js",
      "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.5" / "bootstrap.js"  minified "bootstrap.min.js" dependsOn("jquery.js", "underscore.js", "moment.js"),
      "org.webjars" % "ractive" % "0.7.1" / "ractive.js" minified "ractive.min.js",
      "org.webjars" % "momentjs" % "2.10.6" / "moment.js" minified "moment.min.js"
    )
  )
  private[this] val artifactPath = file(".")
  private val autoAPIMappings    = true
  private val scalaDocOptions    = Seq(
    "-implicits", "-diagrams"
  )

  private lazy val sharedBuildSettings = Seq(
    Keys.organization                                  :=  organization,
    Keys.name                                          :=  "DataRetrieverShared",
    Keys.version                                       :=  "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    Keys.scalaVersion                                  :=  scalaVersion,
    Keys.scalaBinaryVersion                            :=  scalaBinaryVersion,
    Keys.scalacOptions                                 ++= scalacOptions,
    Keys.scalacOptions in (Compile, Keys.doc)          ++= scalaDocOptions ++ Opts.doc.title("DataRetrieverShared"),
    Keys.javacOptions                                  ++= javacOptions,
    Keys.target in (Compile, Keys.doc)                 :=  file("jvm-api"),
    Keys.autoAPIMappings                               :=  autoAPIMappings
  )

  private lazy val jvmBuildSettings = Seq(
    Keys.organization                                  :=  organization,
    Keys.name                                          :=  "DataRetrieverJVM",
    Keys.version                                       :=  "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    Keys.scalaVersion                                  :=  scalaVersion,
    Keys.scalaBinaryVersion                            :=  scalaBinaryVersion,
    Keys.scalacOptions                                 ++= scalacOptions,
    Keys.scalacOptions in (Compile, Keys.doc)          ++= scalaDocOptions ++ Opts.doc.title("DataRetrieverJVM"),
    Keys.javacOptions                                  ++= javacOptions,
    Keys.checksums in Keys.update                      :=  Nil,
    Keys.resolvers                                     ++= Seq(
      "IBM" at "http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/"
    ),
    Keys.libraryDependencies                           ++= jvmLibraryDependencies.value,
    Keys.artifactPath in Keys.`package`                ~=  { defaultPath => artifactPath / defaultPath.getName },
    Keys.artifactName in Keys.`package`                :=  {
      (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
        s"${artifact.name}.${artifact.extension}"
    },
    WebappPlugin.autoImport.webappWebInfClasses        := true,
    LessKeys.compress in Assets                        :=  true,
    WebKeys.webTarget                                  :=  Keys.target.value / "webapp" / "WEB-INF",
    Keys.target in (Compile, Keys.doc)                 :=  file("jvm-api"),
    Keys.autoAPIMappings                               :=  autoAPIMappings
  )

  private lazy val jsBuildSettings = Seq(
    Keys.organization                                  :=  organization,
    Keys.name                                          :=  "DataRetrieverJS",
    Keys.version                                       :=  "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    Keys.scalaVersion                                  :=  scalaVersion,
    Keys.scalaBinaryVersion                            :=  scalaBinaryVersion,
    Keys.scalacOptions                                 ++= scalacOptions,
    Keys.scalacOptions in (Compile, Keys.doc)          ++= scalaDocOptions ++ Opts.doc.title("DataRetrieverJS"),
    Keys.libraryDependencies                           ++= jsLibraryDependencies.value,
    jsDependencies                                     ++= jsWebjarDependencies.value,
    Keys.skip in packageJSDependencies                 :=  false,
    Keys.target in (Compile, Keys.doc)                 :=  file("js-api"),
    Keys.autoAPIMappings                               :=  autoAPIMappings
  ) ++ (
    Seq(packageJSDependencies, fastOptJS, fullOptJS) map { packageJSKey =>
      Keys.crossTarget in(Compile, packageJSKey) := Keys.baseDirectory.value / ".." / "jvm" / "src" / "main" / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "js"
    }
  )

  lazy val root = Project(
      id = "data-retriever-root",
      base = file(".")
  ).aggregate(dataRetrieverJVM, dataRetrieverJS)

  lazy val dataRetriever = CrossProject(
    id = "data-retriever",
    base = file("."),
    crossType = CrossType.Full
  ).settings(
    Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ sharedBuildSettings:_*
  ).jvmSettings(
    Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ jvmBuildSettings:_*
  ).jsSettings(
    Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ jsBuildSettings:_*
  )

  lazy val dataRetrieverJS = dataRetriever.js.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

  lazy val dataRetrieverJVM = dataRetriever.jvm.enablePlugins(WarPlugin, SbtTwirl, SbtWeb)
}
```

**Partial Solution**

```
WebKeys.exportedAssets in Assets := SbtWeb.syncMappings(Keys.streams.value.cacheDirectory, (WebKeys.exportedMappings in Assets).value, Keys.target.value / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "public"),
WebKeys.exportedMappings in Assets := (WebKeys.exportedMappings in Assets).value.map(item => item._1 -> item._2.replaceAll("""(.*(/|\\))*(.*)""", "$3"))
```

This way the assets are copied to *WEB-INF/public* which is great, but sadly sbt-web still copies them to *WEB-INF/classes*.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the *META-INF/resources/webjars/dataretrieverjvm/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT* path might be coming from [`createWebJarMappings`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web/blob/8933ec1928ce291efa50dbed653d3d7560acfdd2/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/web/SbtWeb.scala#L302) in sbt-web.

What happens if you strip it out?

```
WebKeys.exportedMappings in Assets :=
  (WebKeys.exportedMappings in Assets).value map { case (file, string) =>
    import org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.WEBJARS_PATH_PREFIX
    val prefix = s"${WEBJARS_PATH_PREFIX}/${moduleName.value}/${version.value}/"
    (file, string.replace(prefix, ""))
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I've located this piece of code already. I'll check it out tomorrow. I hope I can turn this feature off without forking the plugin. It seems like I could simply skip this step. I'll propose a backwards compatible solution if it's not doable. We'll see.

Comment: @Athelionas, Have you already added the possibility to disable that feature? Or should I use James code to avoid my assets and web resources be placed inside the WEB-INF folder?

Is it advisable to place resources that belong to the project itself inside the META-INF special folder? As far as I know, this folder should only contain information **about** the project (creator, dependencies, service providers, etc), and not a piece of the project.

Comment: Moreover. It's annoying having to know the project's version to be able to read web resources from the project's code (with `ClassLoader#getResource(String)` ).

Comment: Note that for windows you should replace the forward slashes with backward ones.
`val prefix = s"${WEBJARS_PATH_PREFIX}/${moduleName.value}/${version.value}/".relplace("/","\\")`

Comment: Confirming that this works and the `.css` files end in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the `org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator` which helps to resolve partial paths into full paths in webjars. That's how it works: given a link in the HTML page like `<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` a Servlet could be configured to resolve paths against classpath.

Example of a resource manager for Undertow:

```
public class WebLocatorWithClassPathFallbackResourceManager extends ClassPathResourceManager {
    private WebJarAssetLocator webJarAssetLocator = new WebJarAssetLocator();

    public WebLocatorWithClassPathFallbackResourceManager(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String resourcePath) throws IOException {
        try {
            return super.getResource(webJarAssetLocator.getFullPath(resourcePath));
        } catch (MultipleMatchesException|IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // handle mismatch
        }
        return super.getResource(resourcePath);
    }
}
```

Then one could place a servlet to handle `"/*"` mapping and just serve resources from that classpath. It is supposed that your resources are located in `/META-INF/resources` - which is available for Servlet 3.0+.